# VBscript fails to pin items to taskbar on Windows Insider build

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a script that will pin an item to the taskbar in all OS's except the Windows Insider builds. I converted it to a Powershell script and it also works on all OS's except the Windows Insider build. When I run it, I don't get any error messages, nothing in the Event Viewer. MS has been locking down the ability to programmatically pin items to both the Start Menu and the Taskbar. It looks like they're going further in upcoming releases. Has anyone else run into this? Here is the code I'm using.

```
Function PinItem(strFolder, strFile)

    Dim ShortcutPath 
    Dim sKey1
    Dim sKey2
    Dim KeyValue

      '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ShortcutPath = strFolder & "\" & strFile
    sKey1      = "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\{:}\\"
    sKey2      = Replace(sKey1, "\\", "\ExplorerCommandHandler")
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        KeyValue = .RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" & _
            "\CommandStore\shell\Windows.taskbarpin\ExplorerCommandHandler")

        .RegWrite sKey2, KeyValue, "REG_SZ"

        With WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            With .Namespace(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(ShortcutPath))
                With .ParseName(objFSO.GetFileName(ShortcutPath))
                    .InvokeVerb("{:}")
                End With
            End With
        End With

        .Run("Reg.exe delete """ & Replace(sKey1, "\\", "") & """ /F"), 0, True
    End With
End Function
```